Stripe schedule create 90 days (current date + 90days)
I'm facing issue while creating stripe schedule 90 days (current date + 90days) by the stripe session. After the package selection on my page it will redirect on the Stripe UI where customer can enter the payment details.
const line_items = [
      [
        {
          price: "price_1PM8z7P7ZWYXRvciYRvdPmPc", // subscription fee /month interval
          quantity: 1,
        },
        {
          price: "price_1PH2ayP7ZWYXRvcioelaTBhc", // media budget fee /month interval
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    ];

    let subscription_data = {
      description: "Subscription description Loc L1, Loc L2",
    };

  
      subscription_data = {
        ...subscription_data,
        billing_cycle_anchor: 1732905000, // Sat Nov 30 2024 00:00:00
        proration_behavior: "none",
      };
    

    /* subscription_data = {
      ...subscription_data,
      trial_end: 1738348200,
    }; */

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      ui_mode: "embedded",
      mode: "subscription",
      customer: customer,
      line_items: line_items[price_set],
      subscription_data: subscription_data,
      metadata: {
        Loc1Id: "Loc1 description",
        Loc2Id: "Loc2 description",
      },
      return_url: `http://localhost:3000/success?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,

    });

    res.json({
      id: session.id,
      url: session.url,
      client_secret: session?.client_secret,
      session,
    });

It gives me error "billing_cycle_anchor cannot be later than next natural billing date."
I also try to find the solution on the stripe

But this is not the solution of my problem I need some workaround for this.
I need solution or workaround for this problem.

It'd be helpful if you can tell us a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish. The error that Stripe returned explains that you can't set the billing cycle anchor beyond the next billing period. That's because Checkout Sessions immediately create Subscriptions. But it sounds like you may be wanting to wait and create a Subscription in the future? If so, you will want to create a Subscription Schedule for that: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#start-subscription-future

@toby, it create schedule subscription by API but we need to redirect on UI so customer can enter the payment details. In schedule subscription it create schedule and may be customer don't have any payment method in his stripe account.

It's still not clear to me what the flow you're trying to build is. If you want to build a flow that starts a Subscription in the future, then I'd use Subscription Schedules for that. If you want to collect payment method details before creating the Subscription Schedule, then I'd suggest sending your customers through one of the flows shown in Stripe's guide for setting up payment methods for future usage: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse.

@toby, I want to create subscription schedule it will start 24th of the month this flow is completely working, subscriber comes and select plan and redirect to stripe embedded ui where they can add their payment method, Now in one case I've to start the subscription currentDate + 90 days ( 02Nov2024) with the same flow. In this part i'm facing challenge

billing_cycle_anchor or billing_cycle_anchor_config won't help you with this, they don't allow setting a date beyond the recurring cycle of the price (which I presume is a month here).
The only way you can do this within a single Session create call is with a trial period:
subscription_data:{
  trial_period_days:90
}

This may not suit, as you may want to charge the customer on day-one, in which case the solution would be to add a one-time price for day-one:
line_items:[
  {
    price_data: {
      currency: currency,
      product_data: {
        name: 'product name',
      },
      unit_amount: amount,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }

If the look of that setup on session still doesn't work for you, the next way would be with Subscription Schedules (EDIT):
-Create your session with a 90-day price
-Attach a Subscription Schedule to the resulting Subscription
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#existing-subscription
-Set your Subscription Schedule with a new phase that starts after on iteration.
stripe.subscriptionSchedules.update({
  'subsched_id',
  end_behavior: 'release',
  phases: [
    {
      start_date: subsched.phases[0].start_date,
      items: [
        {
          price: 90_day_price,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      iterations: 1,
    },
    {
      items: [
        {
          price: 30_day_price,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});


Note that I'm not suggesting Subscription Schedules. They are a solution, but imo I don't see the point here, as it would be three calls instead of two for the second solution, and would be a lot more complex than the single Subscription update I shared.

It works but when we add trail period it showing: You can use free till date and after that it will $50 month charge. So this message is not good as per the business,  because we not giving free/trail subscription. And if we showing this message then customer can demand he need the service immediately it is free for him til 90days.

I expected that, that's where the "If the look of that setup on session still doesn't work for you" bit.

Switching to a price with a billing interval that is different from the one the Subscription is currently using should result in the Subscription immediately being moved to the new billing period, which will result in the customer being billed for the new price.
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#billing-periods

crap that is true - I forgot that immediate payment behavior. So Subscription Schedules are actually required. I'll update my answer
